# Показать ближайшие места на карте Google

Tags: google-maps-api

Здравствуйте. У меня есть задача - сделать отдельную страницу на сайте, которая будет показывать карту с текущим местоположением пользователя, а в радиусе 5км показывать ближайшие кафе.
Нашел статью на сайте гугл: https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search?hl=ru
но к сожалению ничего не понял, так как с API не дружу. С чего посоветуйте начать читать, чтобы понять как осуществить это все? Или может есть уже готовый пример? Желательно чтобы информацию о местах брало с базы данных.

Comment: Подружитесь с API для начала.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Внедряете скрипт:

```
<script
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&libraries=places&callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>
```

Переменные:

```
var map;
var infowindow;
var myPlace = {lat: 25.276987, lng: 55.296249 };
```

Вызываете функцию поиска ближайших мест по типу:

```
var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
            service.nearbySearch({
                location : myPlace,
                radius : 5000,
                type : [ 'cafe' ]
            }, callback);
```

Проверяете результат поиска и ставите маркеры на карту:

```
function callback(results, status) {
            if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
                for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                    createMarker(results[i]);
                }
            }
        }

function createMarker(place) {
            var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map : map,
                position : place.geometry.location
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                infowindow.setContent(place.name);
                infowindow.open(map, this);
            });
        }
```

Пример можно найти в [Google API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_search_requests), а также [типы мест](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types).

<sub>Перевод [ответа с enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36235936/google-map-api-to-find-nearby-restaurant-around-my-place).</sub>

Comment: Спасибо за направление в нужное русло! По Вашему примеру получилось. Правда при клике на маркер что-то ошибку выдает...


`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setContent' of undefined
    at _.Ke.<anonymous> (index.php?route=information/static:212)
    at Object._.z.trigger (js?key=AIzaSyANhjSkKkfwstcRUPE8eBsqxi7N2-lURtY&libraries=places&callback=initMap:101)
    at wU.handleEvent (marker.js:50)
    at hy._.k.be (map.js:48)
    at hy._.k.Hi (map.js:46)
    at Object._.z.trigger (js?key=AIzaSyANhjSkKkfwstcRUPE8eBsqxi7N2-lURtY&libraries=places&callback=initMap:101)
    at Zp.<a`

Comment: Уже решил эту ошибку, написав вместо `var infowindow;` это - `var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;`